# Use phonegap code in online website

Tags: cordova, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a website based on Twitter Bootstrap. With some extra improvements it runs great on phones and tablets. But I want a real app for it and don't want to duplicate everything. To start, just for Android.

The first thing I've tried was AppsGeyser, pretty easy but not really what I want. If the user doesn't have a internet connection I see those ugly browser messages. And If the user press the menu button on his phone I want the menu from the "menu bar" from Twitter Bootstrap toggles. So AppsGeyser isn't what I want. And no iOS support.

Next I've tried a lot with PhoneGap, fantastic! All I want is possible, but how or what is the best solution? What I want is the follow with my opinion:

- If the app starts it checks for a internet connection, no connection? Load from cache. Else just show the website. HTML5 cache manifest best choise? Played with it, but I only want to load from cache if there is no internet connection. So far it looks like this isn't possible..?
- If some form will be submitted, again, check if there is a internet connection, no internet connection? Just a alert: "no internet connection!" and don't submit so the form is still filled, like the user just did. On click/submit => ajax call to the website => fails? => show alert => return false, so the form won't be submitted. Best choise?
- The last thing I want, like I told before, that when the user presses the menu button on his phone it toggles the "menu bar" from Twitter Bootstrap.

So the first 2 things aren't a problem I think, but the last thing...?
I've found this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#menubutton
Not a big deal if the website is "in the app" but I don't want the website "in the app". Just load it from the internet (or cache if there is no internet connection), so if I change something I don't have to change the website and the app. Just the website! But is it possible to use Cordova in a "remote" website? If the website runs through the app by PhoneGap it runs, and work!?

Like, if I place this code in my website:

```
document.addEventListener("menubutton", onMenuKeyDown, false);

function onMenuKeyDown() {
    alert('Menu button pressed!');
}
```

And include the cordova js file it doesn't do anything for the normal visitors, but If the app is used and the website is loaded from the PhoneGap app withing the webview it works?

Please you're opinion about this all!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To me, the text book approach to this in PhoneGap would be to write the application as a self-contained JavaScript/HTML/CSS application that can sit on the device and retrieve data from a server side web-service. This requires a concerted effort and generally reverse engineering a traditional server-side web-app (which seems to be what you're describing) isn't particularly easy. This model gives you excellent performance and lets you update the applications content without releasing an update.

I think your best bet would be to rewrite the presentation layer of your app as a JavaScript application driven by an API derived from your back-end. This should give you pretty excellent performance which is important if you're competing with other native apps. Plus if you build it right it'll give you offline functionality and more (caching, logging, etc).

The fast approach (but probably not one I'd recommend) would be to package only the home page (HTML/JS/CSS) on the device then just link to your web-content as usual. This isn't an approach I've used before but should work perfectly well. If you wanted to build in offline functionality combining this approach with a toolkit like jQuery Mobile should work well (jQM won't provide offline functionality per sae but should give you a suitable foundation to build your own offline handling).

I hope this helps!

Comment: when you say "then just link to your web-content as usual" at would be the 'usual way'?

Comment: Well, your index.html (embedded in the app) could just link to external web-content with hyperlinks. The external content would just be displayed inside the app and the user is none-the-wiser. Hope that makes sense.